# How to convert tiff format ti jpg or png foemat during upload in PHP

Tags: php, html, web, browser, tiff

I have images which is in tiff format so i want to convert it to png or jpg during upload process in PHP or is there any other way or plugin where i can directly display my tiif image through browsers?

Answer (score 0):

PHP distribution does not support image processing, 
So you need to use ImageMagick, for details [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

You can simplly write a code like this.

```
<?php
// create new imagick object from image.jpg
$im = new Imagick( "image.tiff" );

// change format to png
$im->setImageFormat( "png" );

// output the image to the browser as a png
//header( "Content-Type: image/png" );
//echo $im;

// or you could output the image to a file:
$im->writeImage( "image.png" );
?>
```